# Copy parts from rows only when they are not empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list and want to copy rows from it whom are not empty.

I don't know how to ignore these rows, I could make a normal formula which shows 1 when theres something in and 0 when its all empty. And i only want to copy the rows with stuff filled in.

Does anybody have an idea how i can only copy rows with stuff in it?

Answer (score 1):

The vba method I used was to [autofilter the column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) (in your case, criteria would be "where cells aren't blank").

Next, you can specify that only visible cells should be copied by using [SpecialCells and xlCellTypeVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx).

I hope this approach helps. Please provide some vba code if you need any assistance along the way!